react native firebase phone authentication is not working
1.I created project with package name same as package name in build.gradle.
2.I have added the sha1 and sha256 key correctly to fingerprint in firebase.
3.I enabled the sign-in method in authentication section.
4.download the google-service.json file and replaced the existing file in android/app with this.
5.on my emulator , i installed the google play store.
but, as a result of test, this error occured.
[auth/app-not-authorized] this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication.
please verify that the correct package name, sha-1 and sha-256 are configured in the firebase console. [invalid app info in play_integrit_token]
I want to complish the react native firebase phone authentication.

This question is similar to: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
